# Angular JS-Jasmine how to unit test $location.path().search()?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

been doing some googling but cant find an answer to this little problem of mine. Just trying to test this bit of code from my controller:

```
$scope.viewClientAssets = (id) -> 
  $location.path("/assets").search("client_id", "#{id}")
```

which in turn returns this url:

> http://localhost:3000/admin#/assets?client_id=19

this all works fine however when unit testing......A few assumptions:
I have my spec set up correctly as I have other tests and expectations working perfectly fine so here is the test:

```
it 'checks if view client assets path is correct', ->
    createController()
    #gets rid of unnecessary function calls
    flushRequests()
    #calls the ctrl function with necessary args
    $scope.viewClientAssets(clientData.client.id)
    spyOn($location, 'path')
    spyOn($location, 'search') #tried diff methods here such as 
    # and.returnValue(), .calls.any(), calls.all()
    expect($location.path).toHaveBeenCalledWith("/assets")
    expect($location.path.search).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

all other tests pass however when this gets hit I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'search' of undefined

the console debugger tells me:

```
$scope.createClientAsset = function(id) {
        return $location.path('/assets/create').search("client_id", "" + id);
      };
```

that path is undefined?

any ideas anyone?

Comment: you should consider changing the accepted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are spying on `$location.path` and not returning anything, or returning undefined.

Make your spy return a string (the string you would normally expect, the actual path) and the search function, defined for all strings in javascript, will work normally in your test.

e.g. Do as follows:

```
spyOn($location, 'path').and.returnValue('/client_id/')
$location.path('anything'); // returns '/client_id/'
```

Comment: i get an error for second expect statement:   **Error: Expected a spy, but got undefined.**. I have spy for both methods:   `spyOn($location, 'path').and.returnValue('/active/');
              spyOn($location, 'search');`   and my expectations look like: `expect($location.path).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/test/1');
            expect($location.path.search).toHaveBeenCalled();`  Am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: Check the name of the spy in the expect statement is correct. Post your updated code

Comment: `element = angular.element('<div click-link="\'#/test/1?active=3\'">');
            $compile(element)(scope);
            scope.$digest();

            spyOn($location, 'path').and.returnValue("/active/");
            spyOn($location, 'search');

            element.click();
            expect($location.path).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/test/1');
            expect($location.search).toHaveBeenCalled();`

Comment: Yeah, you are spying on $location.path and $location.search, then checking the spy at $location.path.search. See the problem?

Comment: changing it to $location.search doesn't help. It still gives undefined error. Any other solution?

Comment: Yeah, use spyOn($location.path, 'search') and expect($location.path.search).toHave...

Answer (score 4):

To test the spyOn, for search, do the following

```
spyOn($location, 'path').and.callThrough();
spyOn($location, 'search');
```

That will return values correctly.

Comment: this is the correct answer - should be the accepted answer - many thanks - saved me a lot of effort :)